# Handling a long-running process in a Nest.js app

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

We have a Nest.js app that uses Prisma to interface with a PG database. Within our app, users can bulk upload records via CSV, which can sometimes, involve 1000s of records that need to be processed (validated) and saved. So this process can sometimes take 10, 20, 30 seconds or more.

We're still in testing mode, but even with just a few users, we notice that if someone initiates this process whilst another attempts to use other parts of the application, responses start to slow down significantly.

Presumably, this is because the application is 'blocked' due to being single-threaded, and so the solution would be to offload this process as documented here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues (in the 'separate processes' section).

Is this the correct way of handling such cases? Or is there something else we should be looking at?

Comment: Why don't you just capture the user's request, store the request in DB and the excel file to some CDN or just on the server and then add a scheduler that will take each record from the DB and then process it sequentially. Other way is to use queues instead of the DB. 
NestJS Scheduler: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling

Comment: @NirajChauhan thank you Niraj! Appreciate the link to. Yes, I suppose that was my question; is this the what should in theory be done? As in, should any long running process (regardless of whether it's I/O or CPU intensive) be offloaded to a queue, to avoid blockages?

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this, but the idea is to make it async by passing it to some other process/thread/service to do it.

Comment: Does your database have an appropriate number of connections depending upon your traffic? It might also be possible that some requests would need to wait till a connection can be free to process it.

Comment: A very "cheap" solution is to just pass the data to an async function that you do not await and then create the response for your request. If you perform async operations (e.g. database calls, i/o, ...) in the "long-running" process, this will not block your application.